# Package Function Confusion

Tags: packages

I am a freshman working with *Mathematica*. I have written a package with a function like this:

```
SolidShapeFunction2d[Coords_List] := 
  Module[{u, p1, p2, p3, u1, u2, u3},
    u = p1 + p2 * x + p3 * y;
    x1 = Coords[[1, 1]];
    y1 = Coords[[1, 2]];
    x2 = Coords[[2, 1]];
    y2 = Coords[[2, 2]];
    x3 = Coords[[3, 1]];
    y3 = Coords[[3, 2]];
    solut1 = 
      Solve[{
        (u /. x -> x1 /. y -> y1) == u1, 
        (u /. x -> x2 /. y -> y2) == u2, 
        (u /. x -> x3 /. y -> y3) == u3},
        {p1, p2, p3}];
    u = u /. solut1;
    N1 = Coefficient[u, u1];
    N2 = Coefficient[u, u2];
    N3 = Coefficient[u, u3];
    {{N1, 0, N2, 0, N3, 0}, {0, N1, 0, N2, 0, N3}}]
```

This function is designed to obtain the shape function in FEM. But when I use this in a notebook, the answer doesn't seem correct:

```
<< MyFem`
Nshape = SolidShapeFunction2d[Coords]
```

> ```
> {{{1 - MyFem`Private`x}, 0, {MyFem`Private`x - MyFem`Private`y}, 0, 
>     {MyFem`Private`y}, 0}, 
>  {0, {1 - MyFem`Private`x}, 0, {MyFem`Private`x - MyFem`Private`y}, 0, 
>     {MyFem`Private`y}}}
> ```

What does the `` MyFem`Private` `` mean? And how can eliminate it?

Comment: `Begin` statement in your package makes new symbols to create in given context. You don't want to see this context or what? I rather think there is a problem in definition, unless you really want symbolic output.

Comment: @ Kuba.In this function,I do want the symbolic output. Because in the next function(I don't post here),some value will be bound to the "X" and "Y".And the function will be evaluted to obtain numerical answer.

Comment: I think this is in fact a good question.

Comment: It's your use of an undefined x and y while in the Private part of the context of your package. It's rather bad practice to use and return those. If you want to return symbols from a global context I guess it would be better to introduce those as parameters to functions that you call from this package. So, function template should look like `SolidShapeFunction2d[Coords_List,x_,y_] `

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries.Thanks for your answer. I will hava a try and report later.

Comment: @Kuba If you call the function from a Global context that wouldn't be necessary. Using $CellContext for a package sounds like a bad idea, but I don't have much experience with that, so I can't really tell.

Comment: @kuba and I saw you later comment too late. Too bad...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries,@Kuba.Thanks for your answers and help. I think I have solved this problem.Actually speaking,when I write this function, I don't really think how to use it. After finishing this function, the trouble I post above occures to me.But,anyway,it has gone.

Comment: @Yang It would be nice if you could to self answer the question.

Comment: I actually also think it is best to let the user provide the symbols which are used for `x` and `y`. The only reasonable alternative I know would be to use the special "formal" cahracters which are reserved for such purposes since version 9, they create symbols which are in the System context and protected. One can create them with shortcuts like Esc-$x-Esc or the special characters palette, but it probably is something which as to be explained to potential users of your function...

Answer (score 1):

This question has been solved with the help from comments above.
In fact, I have to say,I don't really think how to use this function when I begin to edit.In the process of discussing with others, I think there are two ways to solve this problem.

If I really want a symbolic output, I must define or declare X and Y at the beginning of the Private part.But I don't think it is a good way because the system will give warnnings when you load the package, and two important and often-used symbolic variable will be shadowed.

The another way is rewriting the function just like following:

```
SolidShapeFunction2d[Coords_List,x_,y_]
```

From my experience, the second way is encouraged。